# Colorful bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, colors

I want to write a bash script that prints some information to the terminal STDOUT. For better readability and structure, I would like to color the different items and highlight them this way.

Now, is there a Bash equivalent to the Windows-CMD/DOS command `COLOR` which sets the currently used background and font color? And how do I reset the color back to the terminal default after finishing my script?

Edit:
I have read [Pipable command to print in color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135214), but only some answers are written in Bash so that they can be easily included in my script. Besides this, the answers there lack the following points I want:

- change background color
- display white foreground color, the default color set in `gnome-terminal` gets displayed instead (which is neon green for me)
- make all available colors accessible somehow, not only a small subset by keywords. I could imagine e.g. some kind of RGB encoding to pass as function argument for easily specifying a color.

Comment: @dschinn1001 I don't understand what `gedit` has to do with that. It's a GUI editor, not for the terminal.

Comment: @ByteCommander - sorry, now I know what you mean - have misunderstood you but in google there is much output with terms "howto write bash-script with colour output"

Comment: I have read some that insert some very cryptic strings into the text to output, for changing the color, but I hoped there has to be something easier...

Comment: @muru The question you linked is only a subset of mine. I want more! ;-)

Comment: @ByteCommander most terminals in use support 256 colours, not the full RGB set. You want 256 names in your code? Are you insane?

Comment: Also, the first answer links to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash for a more complete set of colours, including *background colours*.

Comment: @muru No, as I said I don't want to reference them by keyword, but 256 colors can be described as RGB values with 2 bit per channel + 2 bit brightness for example. Or 2 bit red, 3 bit green, 3 bit blue, whatever encoding is used. This can then easily be reproduced and manually "mixed" to the desired color and given as parameter.

Comment: @ByteCommander have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xterm_256color_chart.svg, then make an array. Good luck with that.

Comment: You may want to check out the ansi escape codes. IIRC these are supported by linux terminals.

Answer (score 2):

A small script to get the cryptic codes **;)**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   This file echoes a bunch of color codes to the 
#   terminal to demonstrate what's available.  Each 
#   line is the color code of one forground color,
#   out of 17 (default + 16 escapes), followed by a 
#   test use of that color on all nine background 
#   colors (default + 8 escapes).
#

T='gYw'   # The test text

echo -e "\n                 40m     41m     42m     43m\
     44m     45m     46m     47m";

for FGs in '    m' '   1m' '  30m' '1;30m' '  31m' '1;31m' '  32m' \
           '1;32m' '  33m' '1;33m' '  34m' '1;34m' '  35m' '1;35m' \
           '  36m' '1;36m' '  37m' '1;37m';
  do FG=${FGs// /}
  echo -en " $FGs \033[$FG  $T  "
  for BG in 40m 41m 42m 43m 44m 45m 46m 47m;
    do echo -en "$EINS \033[$FG\033[$BG  $T  \033[0m";
  done
  echo;
done
echo
```

[image]

---

The code is easy to read from the table that generated the previous script.

`\e[1;37m\e[44m`

- `\e[1;37m` – Foreground
- `\e[44m` – Background

---

Some examples

- White foreground

  ```
  TOA="\e[0m" # No Color
  whiteForeground="\e[1;37m" 
  echo -e "${whiteForeground}foo${TOA}"
  ```
- White on blue

  ```
  TOA="\e[0m" # No Color
  whiteOnBlue="\e[1;37m\e[44m" 
  echo -e "${whiteOnBlue}foo${TOA}"
  ```

---

And a sample bash script:

```
red="\e[0;31m"
green="\e[0;32m"
yellow="\e[0;33m"
blue="\e[0;34m"
TOA="\e[0m" # No Color

if [[ $cfg_log_level == "" ]]; then
  cfg_log_level=4
fi

function logError () {
  if [[ $cfg_log_level == "1" ]] || [[ $cfg_log_level == "2" ]] || [[ $cfg_log_level == "3" ]] || [[ $cfg_log_level == "4" ]]; then
    echo -e "${red}$1${TOA}" 1>&2
  fi
}

function logWarn () {
  if [[ $cfg_log_level == "2" ]] || [[ $cfg_log_level == "3" ]] || [[ $cfg_log_level == "4" ]]; then
    echo -e "${yellow}$1${TOA}" 1>&2
  fi
}

function logInfo () {
  if [[ $cfg_log_level == "3" ]] || [[ $cfg_log_level == "4" ]]; then
    echo -e "${green}$1${TOA}" 1>&2
  fi
}

function logDebug () {
  if [[ $cfg_log_level == "4" ]]; then
    echo -e "${blue}$1${TOA}" 1>&2
  fi
}
```

Comment: Wow!  Saved to ` /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tput`

- `tput setaf <color>` sets the foreground color
- `tput setab <color>` sets the background color

the colors are 1 bit *b,g,r*:

```
  0. black
  1. red
  2. green
  3. yellow
  4. blue
  5. magenta
  6. cyan
  7. white
```

tput can set other attributes of the characters such as underline, bold, blink etc. see `man terminfo` for more information.

I think that a good way of using this is by setting variables shemantically. i.e.

```
startheader=`tput setaf 0``tput setab 7`
endheader=`tput sgr0`
startprompt=`tput bold`
endprompt=$endheader

echo ${startheader}The Header${endheader}
echo -n ${startprompt}Enter value: ${endprompt}
read value
```