# How can i format output from an aliased command (`weather EPWR`)?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've created an alias in `~/.bashrc`, which executes `weather EPWR` which gives me current weather informations in the following form:

```
jjj:~$ do-I-need-a-jacket 
Searching via station...
[caching result Wroclaw Ii, Poland]
Current conditions at Wroclaw Ii, Poland (EPWR) 51-06N 016-53E 121M
   Last updated Nov 19, 2015 - 07:00 AM EST / 2015.11.19 1200 UTC
   Temperature: 53 F (12 C)
   Relative Humidity: 76%
   Wind: from the WNW (290 degrees) at 18 MPH (16 KT)
   Weather: Cumulonimbus clouds observed
   Sky conditions: partly cloudy
```

<sup>(same text [as screenshot on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhFbD.png) or [plain text on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/5tUGPm1t))</sup>

What steps do I need to take to customize this output so that temperatures will be highlighted red and humidity e.g. blue?  Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Mind to post the output as text as well so that we can test?

Comment: Done. Sorry, I did not think it would be helpful.

Comment: No problem, there's (another) problem though, apparently lines from "Temperature [...]" onwards are indented, what's used for the intendation? A tabulation? Spaces? How many?

Comment: If these are spaces, then 3 i guess. I have no idea how to check it. Plaintext on pastebin? Done.

Comment: @kos 3 spaces I would assume. a tab with odd numbers is odd :P

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/677175/367990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `do-i-need-a-jacket` to this Perl command:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^(   Temperature: )(.*)/){print("$1\e[31m$2\e[0m\n")}elsif(/^(   Relative Humidity: )(.*)/){print("$1\e[34m$2\e[0m\n")}else{print}'
```

Expanded into a script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

-t STDIN && exit;

while(<STDIN>) {
    if(/^(   Temperature: )(.*)/) {
        print("$1\e[31m$2\e[0m\n")
    }
    elsif(/^(   Relative Humidity: )(.*)/) {
        print("$1\e[34m$2\e[0m\n")
    }
    else {
        print
    }
}
```

[image: s1]

You can colorize other lines with other colors by adding other `elsif` blocks after the `if` block and before the `else` block (you'll have to change the string to match and the ANSI color escape sequence to match the desired color):

```
elsif(/^(   Temperature: )(.*)/) { # Change this to the string to match ("Wind", "Weather", "Sky conditions", ...)
    print("$1\e[31m$2\e[0m\n") # Change this to the ANSI color escape sequence to match the desired color
}
```

List of possible ANSI color escape sequences:

[image: s2]

Comment: Wow, that looks huge! Should I guess i should paste `alias do-i-need-a-jacket='weather EPWR | perl -ne \'if(/^(   Temperature: )(.*)/){print("$1\e[31m$2\e[0m\n")}elsif(/^(   Relative Humidity: )(.*)/){print("$1\e[34m$2\e[0m\n")}else{print}\''` to .bashrc, right? Well, it prints an error, when i try to run `. ~/.bashrc`. How can i deal with these extra apostrophes inside perl command?

Comment: @bowl I'd better have tested :) this works: `alias do-i-need-a-jacket='weather EPWR | perl -ne "if(/^(   Temperature: )(.*)/){print(\"\$1\e[31m\$2\e[0m\n\")}elsif(/^(   Relative Humidity: )(.*)/){print(\"\$1\e[34m\$2\e[0m\n\")}else{print}"'`

Comment: @bowl Watch out that sequences of spaces are trimmed to a single space in comments, you'll have to add two spaces before "Temperature" and two spaces before "Relative Humidity"

Comment: sorry, but it does not work for me.  `. ~/.bashrc` prints no error and command works, still with no colour changed. I may need to say specifically that i have changed font's colour in terminal settings. But you may have seen it on screenshot already.  I have tried pasting your code with one and two spaces before keywords. Neither worked.
What's more, i have pasted `weather EPWR | perl -ne "if(/^( Temperature: )(.*)/){print(\"$1\e[31m$2\e[0m\n\")}elsif(/^( Relative Humidity: )(.*)/){print(\"$1\e[34m$2\e[0m\n\")}else{print}"` directly into command line and it did not color output either.

Comment: @bowl That's rather strange. The text colored at the terminal level shouldn't affect this. Mind to post your `~/.bashrc` content (inclusive of the non-working alias) at [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com)? Obviously feel free to obfuscate personal data if any.

Comment: Of course I don't mind, as you are trying to help me as best as you can. It's hearth-melting. Here you go, my bashrc file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13365159/

Comment: @bowl Ok, the problem is the number of spaces; you need exactly three spaces before "Temperature" and three spaces before "Relative Humidity" (you currently have only two in your `~/.bashrc`) and exactly one space between "Relative" and "Humidity" (you currently have two in your `~/.bashrc`), it worked for me right after these corrections. Let me know if this avails (it should though).

Comment: It works now. Thank you for your time and elaborated answers. You're really helpful a person.

Comment: @bowl Glad that it helped! Also check out the answer below, which is very useful to colorize output using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Regex Colored Glasses" from [Linux Hacks](http://backupfedora.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/home/linux/jot/linux%20hacks/LinuxServerHacks-code/ch07/rcg), here are two ways:

```
# Colors the whole line
weather EPWR | rcg 'Temperature.*$' "RED" 'Relative Humidity.*' "BLUE"
```

or

```
# Color the values 
weather EPWR | rcg '\-?\d+ F \(\-?\d+ C\)' "RED" '\d+%' "BLUE"
```

Here's what the last command produces:

```
$ weather EPWR | rcg '\-?\d+ F \(\-?\d+ C\)' "RED" '\d+%' "BLUE"|od -bc
0000000 123 145 141 162 143 150 151 156 147 040 166 151 141 040 163 164
          S   e   a   r   c   h   i   n   g       v   i   a       s   t
0000020 141 164 151 157 156 056 056 056 012 133 143 141 143 150 151 156
          a   t   i   o   n   .   .   .  \n   [   c   a   c   h   i   n
0000040 147 040 162 145 163 165 154 164 040 127 162 157 143 154 141 167
          g       r   e   s   u   l   t       W   r   o   c   l   a   w
0000060 040 111 151 054 040 120 157 154 141 156 144 135 012 103 165 162
              I   i   ,       P   o   l   a   n   d   ]  \n   C   u   r
0000100 162 145 156 164 040 143 157 156 144 151 164 151 157 156 163 040
          r   e   n   t       c   o   n   d   i   t   i   o   n   s    
0000120 141 164 040 127 162 157 143 154 141 167 040 111 151 054 040 120
          a   t       W   r   o   c   l   a   w       I   i   ,       P
0000140 157 154 141 156 144 040 050 105 120 127 122 051 040 065 061 055
          o   l   a   n   d       (   E   P   W   R   )       5   1   -
0000160 060 066 116 040 060 061 066 055 065 063 105 040 061 062 061 115
          0   6   N       0   1   6   -   5   3   E       1   2   1   M
0000200 012 114 141 163 164 040 165 160 144 141 164 145 144 040 116 157
         \n   L   a   s   t       u   p   d   a   t   e   d       N   o
0000220 166 040 061 071 054 040 062 060 061 065 040 055 040 060 061 072
          v       1   9   ,       2   0   1   5       -       0   1   :
0000240 060 060 040 120 115 040 105 123 124 040 057 040 062 060 061 065
          0   0       P   M       E   S   T       /       2   0   1   5
0000260 056 061 061 056 061 071 040 061 070 060 060 040 125 124 103 012
          .   1   1   .   1   9       1   8   0   0       U   T   C  \n
0000300 040 040 040 124 145 155 160 145 162 141 164 165 162 145 072 040
                      T   e   m   p   e   r   a   t   u   r   e   :    
0000320 033 133 063 061 155 065 063 040 106 040 050 061 062 040 103 051
        033   [   3   1   m   5   3       F       (   1   2       C   )
0000340 033 133 060 155 012 040 040 040 122 145 154 141 164 151 166 145
        033   [   0   m  \n               R   e   l   a   t   i   v   e
0000360 040 110 165 155 151 144 151 164 171 072 040 033 133 063 064 155
              H   u   m   i   d   i   t   y   :     033   [   3   4   m
0000400 066 066 045 033 133 060 155 012 040 040 040 127 151 156 144 072
          6   6   % 033   [   0   m  \n               W   i   n   d   :
0000420 040 146 162 157 155 040 164 150 145 040 127 040 050 062 067 060
              f   r   o   m       t   h   e       W       (   2   7   0
0000440 040 144 145 147 162 145 145 163 051 040 141 164 040 061 062 040
              d   e   g   r   e   e   s   )       a   t       1   2    
0000460 115 120 110 040 050 061 060 040 113 124 051 012
          M   P   H       (   1   0       K   T   )  \n
0000474
```

Don't re-invent wheels - find one to copy.

Comment: I don't have Linux Hacks installed. And I think i'll try to do it in Perl.

Comment: "Linux Hacks" is a book, the link takes you to the Perl source for `rcg`, an example from the book.

Comment: Didn't know about that script, pretty nifty.